# Push object into array causes permission denied in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

From a child window, I was calling a function in the parent window that pushed an object i.e. {a:0,b:1,c:2} into an array. All works fine in Firefox, but in IE it was pushing the following into the array.

```
[{<Permission denied>}]
```

Rather than:

```
[{a:0,b:1,c:2}]
```

Comment: Can you improve the question so that the answer is more useful?

Comment: hmmm looks like some of my question didn't make it as I'm pretty sure that's not how I left the question. Looks like it removed <permission denied> :)

Comment: Can you not edit the question now?

Answer (score 1):

So the fix I found is as follows:

```
var myArray = [];

var obj = {a:0,b:1,c:2};//object passed through from child window

obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

myArray.push(obj);
```